# No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Devart.Data.Oracle'

Tags: entity-framework-6.1, devart, devforce

I'm using  Devforce 7.2.4, Devart - dotConnect for Oracle 8.4.313, Entity Framework 6.1.2.

I got that error when i set DevForceEnabled property to true on my model.edmx

However I found the link = http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html

web.config code

```
<configSections>
  <section name="ideablade.configuration" type="IdeaBlade.Core.Configuration.IdeaBladeSection, IdeaBlade.Core" />
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<entityFramework>
  <providers
    <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.Oracle" type="Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices, Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=8.4.313.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
  </providers> 
</entityFramework>

<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="Devart.Data.Oracle" />
    <add name="dotConnect for Oracle" invariant="Devart.Data.Oracle" description="Devart dotConnect for Oracle" type="Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleProviderFactory, Devart.Data.Oracle, Version=8.4.313.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Any idea if Devforce and Devart still working together or I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I used Devart in one of my project and I remember getting this error when the version within the provider section's type in the web.config did not match any of the assemblies in the GAC. Could you please check to see if the Devart.Data.Oracle.dll version in the GAC is actually 8.4.313.0? If you had installed an update, it might have updated the assembly version without updating your versions in the web.config

Comment: But the problem made when i set DevForceEnabled = true

Comment: DevForce is provider agnostic, so should work with whatever EF works with.  If you're getting this error at build time, add the provider info from your web.config to the app.config in the model's project.

Comment: Kim thanks for your answer but I already did it. I tried install a new "Windows" and create a new silverlight project with devforce template, devart, EF6.1.2 and added new edmx however didn't work

Comment: Are you using the Code First template?  Was this working with an earlier EF version?

Comment: No, I'm using Data Base first. Working with EF6.0.2, DevArt 8.4.313 and Devforce 7.2.2

Comment: Are you getting the error when building the project, or at run time?

Comment: The error thrown when try "Run Custom Tools" at .tt file

Answer (score 0):

A few more things to look at -

- Make sure you have the correct version number(s) for the Devart
  assemblies.  Your web.config is using two different version numbers.
- The Devart assemblies should be available in the bin folder or the GAC.  If the GAC, they should also be specified under the
  compilation/assemblies element in the web.config.
- Check that your connection string is using the correct provider name.
- Delete the *.edmx.tt, and any other .tt that might have been generated by EF.  When you re-save the model DevForce will generate a new *.edmx.tt.
- Check the 'DevForce' pane in the output window for any additional messages.

Comment: - Devart version at web.config, GAC and bin folder OK  - Provider name OK  
- I follow your instructions about edmx.tt file. But the error still alive.  
- 'DevForce' output window message: Attempting to locate and handle any CSDL/SSDL mismatches in: MyModel.edmx

Comment: Afraid I'm out of ideas. If you've paid for support, send a repro solution to ideabladesupport and we'll see if we can diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug when using Oracle with EF 6.1, and was fixed in DevForce 7.2.6, available on NuGet.